# countably additive function P

Tags: probability, measure-theory

This problem comes from exercise 1.3.5(b) of 'A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory'. It asks to give an example of a countably additive function $P$, defined on all subsets of $[0,1]$, which satisfies countable additivity and $P(A \bigoplus r)=P(A)$, $0\leq r \leq 1$(r-shift), but it does not satisfy $P([a,b])=P((a,b])=P([a,b))=P((a,b))$,$0\leq a \leq b \leq 1$. Can anyone give me a example?

Comment: Isn't the exact condition P([a,b])=P((a,b])=P([a,b))=P((a,b))=b-a? You are missing the b-a part.

Answer (score 4):

Let me write $PA$ for $P(A)$, to save us some parentheses.

Note first that the invariance under translation gives us that $P\{0\}=P\{x\}$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. I claim that this common value must be different from $0$. The reason is that, otherwise, $P[a,b]=P(a,b]=P[a,b)=P(a,b)$ for all $a\le b$, a contradiction. It follows that $P\{0\}=P\{x\}\ne0$. Countable additivity now gives us that $PA=r|A|$ if $A$ is finite, and $PA=\infty$ if $A$ is infinite, where $r=P\{0\}$. In particular, $P[a,a]=r$ but $P(a,a]=P\emptyset=0$. This is the only instance of "intervals" where the chain of equalities does not hold.

(In particular, there are no examples where $P$ is a probability measure.)